# Почему в Java нет коллекций типа Queue?

Tags: java, коллекции, очередь

Смотрю туториал и вижу такие слова:

> В Java коллекции делятся на три основных группы: Set — множество, List — список, Map — словарь (или карта).

Первый вопрос, а где Queue? Причем не только в этом туториале (платном), но и в других так пишется, а где очередь? Объясните пожалуйста эту ситуацию

Comment: Queue там же, где и остальные ADT - в пакете java.util. Просто автор руководства не считает очереди _основными_.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Извините, не очень понял, можете расписать пожалуйста? Я просто начинающий :)

Comment: Что именно вы не поняли? В Java есть [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). Класс Queue находится в пакете java.util, там же где классы Set, List и Map.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а почему нигде про них не говорят? Почему Set, List, Map всегда говорится, а про Queue тишина? Они же тоже относят к Collections

Comment: Может потому, что они используются реже. Может потому, что вы выбираете не самые лучшие источники информации.

Comment: Queue это интерфейс. Одна из его реализаций LinkedList

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Почему в Java нет коллекций типа Queue?

Есть. Как интерфейс [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) так и его реализации, например, [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

> а где Queue?

Не знаю. Может забыли? :-) А может, почему-то считают, что очередь чем-то похожа на список (зависит от определения списка на самом деле). В этом может помочь то, что, пожалуй, наиболее распространенная реализация `Queue` это класс-список `LinkedList`.

Второй вариант подтверждает статья на англовики по Java Collections Framework в которой есть раздел «[Three Types of Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework#Three_Types_of_Collection)» в котором пишется следующее:

> There are three generic types of collection: ordered lists, dictionaries/maps, and sets.
>
> Ordered lists allows the programmer to insert items in a certain order and retrieve those items in the same order. An example is a waiting list. The base interfaces for ordered lists are called List and Queue.
>
> *Есть три основных типа коллекций: упорядоченные списки, словари/карты и множества*
>
> *Упорядоченные списки позволяют программисту вставлять элементы в определенном порядке и вытаскивать их в в том же порядке. Примером является список ожидания. Базовыми интерфейсами для упорядоченных списков являются List и Queue.*

Цитата указывает на книгу Cay S. Horstmann «Big Java Early Objects» возможно оттуда это и пошло.

Определение упорядоченных списков кажется странным и путанным. Возможно автор хотел помочь начинающим программистам быстро запомнить основные типы коллекций и особо не заботился о формальной точности. `Deque` и `Stack` автор тоже видимо относит к спискам.

В [документации по Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) я никакого разделения на три группы не нашел. В-общем, если определения и классификация данные в туториале помогают Вам уяснить картину то это хорошо, но в итоге итогов ориентироваться лучше на документацию.

Comment: Вам приходилось работать с очередями?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Да, теми же `LinkedList` и `PriorityQueue`. Еще есть много реализаций `Queue` в java.util.concurrent которые полезны при многопоточной работе.

Comment: Странно сейчас проволился в Idea в интерфейс Collection и там сразу сверху вижу список аля: Set, List, Map и тд, а Queue и PriorityQueue не вижу :/, кто-то скрывает их специально? :D

Comment: А не лучше ли использовать в качестве реализации очереди ArrayDeque вместо LinkedList? Цитирую: *"This class is likely to be ... faster than LinkedList when used as a queue."*

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван не знаю даже в чем может быть дело :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov В большинстве случаев наверное лучше. Собственно, я в ответе указал на `LinkedList` как на пример списка (`List`), который одновременно является очередью. Что использовать там уже каждый решит сам по ситуации.

Answer (score 4):

Интерфейс Queue наследует от интерфейса Collection.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html